# Routing packets between IPv4 and IPv6 networks on different Interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, router, ipv4

I have a Linux-Board with two Ethernet-Interfaces (eth0, eth1).
On eth0 I have a IPv4 network, on eth1 there's a IPv6 network.
Now I want to route packets from specific devices on the IPv4-network to the IPv6-network and vice versa. Each IPv4-device has a unique IPv6-address and each IPv6-device has a unique IPv4-adress which shall be specified in a textfile.
I read about tayga but it seems that I can use it with only one eth-interface. I don't know if this is really what I need.
Isn't it possible to manage this with standard linux tools?
Do you think a simple C-program which receives IP-Packages on one interface, changes the IP-addresses and IP-PDU-Layout, and sends it back on the other interface will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly I think the best solution for you would be to use [SIIT-DC (SIIT-DC: Stateless IP/ICMP Translation for IPv6 Data Center Environments)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7755). It allows you to map an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address and vice versa.

The tool to do this with I personally like best is [Jool](https://www.jool.mx/en/index.html). It is a Linux kernel module that implements both NAT64 and SIIT.